# store listbox selections in a variable in Qlikview

Tags: qlikview

I have a listbox in Qlikview (version 11) with 4 possible values: a, b, c and d.

I need to know when b and c are selected simultaneously from the listbox. What is a good way to do this? (with or without macros)
Is there a way to put the current selections in a variable, perhaps?

Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 2):

You could use the function created for this purpose:

```
= GetCurrentSelections(Column)
```

Or, you could count the current selections and concatenate them in your own way:

```
= IF(
    GetSelectedCount(Column),
    'Selected: ' & CONCAT(Column, ' and '),
    'No Current Selections!'
)
```

Where `Column` is the name of your column, of course.